# ImportError: No module named google.protobuf.text_format

Tags: python, ubuntu

I can find the `text_format.py` file inside the folder  `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/`.
But in my python program,I have error as `ImportError: No module named google.protobuf.text_format`.
I set `PYTHONPATH` and `echo $PYTHONPATH` gives me

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf:
```

Why this line `from google.protobuf.text_format import Merge` in my python program can't import `google.protobuf.text_format`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is because of having two python2.7 in my system. One is Anacoda and another one is Python2.7 installed. I think, because of mishandling, there are some conflicts. So I uninstall Anacoda and reinstall all required packages manually. Then the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a blank file in the folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/` with name `__init__.py`

run this command and it will do it:

```
touch /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/__init__.py
```

Check if any issues thereafter.

Comment: I have blank __init__.py there.

Comment: I run with sudo to your command. no error shown.nothing come out. Stll have the same error

Comment: @batuman you should have an **__init__.py** file (two underscores before and after `init`), not `init.py`.